# How to pass multiple values for a single URL parameter?

Tags: python, django, url, urlencode

Is it possible to pass multiple values for a single URL parameter without using your own separator?

What I want to do is that the backend expects an input parameter `urls` to have one or more values. It can me set to a single or multiple URLs. What is a way to set the urls parameter so it can have multiple values? I can't use my own separator because it can be part of the value itself.

Example:
    http://example.com/?urls=[value,value2...]

The `urls` parameter be set to just `http://google.com` or it can be set to `http://google.com` `http://yahoo.com ...`. In the backend, I want to process each url as a separate values.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
http://.../?urls=foo&urls=bar&...
```

...

```
request.GET.getlist('urls')
```

Answer (score 8):

The following is probably the best way of doing it - ie, don't specify a delimited list of URLs, rather, use the fact you can specify the same param name multiple times, eg:

```
http://example.com/?url=http://google.co.uk&url=http://yahoo.com
```

The URL list be then be used and retrieved via `request.GET.getlist('url')`