# Django REST API doint filter and on the same field

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm all new to django REST API and trying to understand something.
when using a URI like this:

```
http://example.com/api/products?category=clothing&category=shoes
```

I would have wanted to recieve back all the category that are *clothing* **and** *shoes* but at the ened the only thing that I get is all the *shoes*

what is the correct way to make it act as needed by me?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/a/13261403/1587534

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) at DRF (Django Rest Framework) should help you with what you're trying to do:

In essence you need to override the *queryset* method and look for *query_params*:

Below is an example from DRF's documentation:

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
    by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
    """
    queryset = Purchase.objects.all()
    username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
    if username is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(purchaser__username=username)
    return queryset
```

Comment: Thank you! but I cant understrand a part of it. In my case I need an AND filter on the same field (category) but in the answear it will give me only the last value of "category" and not all of them, or maybe I dont realy understand how would the request look like.

one more thing I've seen the SearchFilter in the doc but not sure if it is the right direction.

Comment: You might want to use the *getlist('category')* option. Something along the lines of 

request.GET.getlist('category')